# Does Aurora Serverless (Postgres) support foreign data wrappers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

As as experiment, I've created two Aurora databases, one serverless and one not, to test whether or not outbound connections are possible with Aurora Serverless. Both databases are in identical subnet groups with identical security groups.

The serverless instance returns this error message:

```
DETAIL:  could not connect to server: Connection timed out
Is the server running on host "xxxx" (xxxx) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

The "regular" instance created a foreign schema and imported the requested tables as expected.Is there a setting or parameter that I need to adjust, or is this functionality not supported due to the architecture that enables this particular offering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently not. From the Aurora Users Guide:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.html

> Outbound communications such as those enabled by Amazon RDS for
> PostgreSQL extensions aren't supported. For example, you can't access
> external data with the postgres_fdw/dblink extension. For more
> information about RDS PostgreSQL extensions, see PostgreSQL on Amazon
> RDS in the RDS User Guide.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it does, you can check this by running the following query on Aurora Serverless:

```
show rds.extensions;
```

There will be a few in the list, with `postgres_fdw` being one of them.

Comment: you can get a tabular view by running `select * from pg_available_extensions() order by name`

Comment: The postgres version may support the extension, but the external communication from one RDS cluster to another is blocked.